# Finding the residue of an infinite series

Tags: residue-calculus

I want to find the residue of
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!(1-z^n)} $$
at $z=1$. I've tried
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!(1-z^n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n!(1-z^n)} - \frac{1}{n!} \right) = 1-e +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!(1-z^n)} $$
but I don't really see how to get the summand into a multiple of $(z-1)^n$ after this.

Comment: $1-z^n = (1-z)(\sum z^k)$.

Comment: This series has convergence issues. Define $w_k=\exp(2\pi i/k)$. Then the $k$-th term of your series will have $1-w_k^k=0$ in the denominator. Since the $w_k$ come arbitrarily close to $z=1$, it isn't possible to just cut out a small disk around $z=1$ to avoid this. This isn't to say that the singularities aren't removable, but convergence certainly has to be investigated carefully. If they turn out not to be removable, the function can't be holomorphic at $1$ even after multiplication by $(1-z)$

Comment: @RobertShore $z^n-1$ has $n$ roots, not only the root at $z=1$.